# Obtain user reputation without Flair

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, api

Stack Overflow Flair's design is becoming a bit old school. So I'm not in the mood of putting it in to my website.

Is there an easy way to obtain my reputation in Stack Overflow to show it in another website without the Flair?

Comment: [Call the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)?

Comment: *"Stack Overflow Flair's design is becoming a bit old school."* How, exactly? Just because it's been around a long time and has become recognizable? Or is there something about the design that you think looks out of date?

Comment: @CodyGray It does look pretty dated to be fair.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. What would you change, @DavidG? More lens flair?

Comment: @CodyGray It doesn't even change as I scroll through the page. No parallax at all.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd rather go with Michael Bay than JJ Abrams, so explosions.

Comment: I'm seeing plenty of explosions on Stack Exchange these days. Michael Bay would be proud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [DavidG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390652/obtain-user-reputation-without-flair#comment736541_390652), I found that user information including reputation can be obtained by sending a request to the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com).

This endpoint:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{id}?site=stackoverflow
```

gives a JSON object of the form:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "badge_counts": {
            "bronze": 55,
            "silver": 27,
            "gold": 6
        },
        "account_id": 2799929,
        "is_employee": false,
        "last_modified_date": 1570000093,
        "last_access_date": 1571678969,
        "reputation_change_year": 761,
        "reputation_change_quarter": 341,
        "reputation_change_month": 52,
        "reputation_change_week": 10,
        "reputation_change_day": 0,
        "reputation": 5390,
        "creation_date": 1369206163,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "user_id": 2408342,
        "accept_rate": 90,
        "location": "Ragama, Sri Lanka",
        "website_url": "",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2408342/roshana-pitigala",
        "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Xyn.jpg?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Roshana Pitigala"
    }],
    "has_more": false,
    "quota_max": 300,
    "quota_remaining": 299
}
```

---

Live example:

```js
function load() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  $('#form').html('Loading...');
  $.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/" + id + "?site=stackoverflow",
    function(data) {
      $('#form').hide();
      $('#rep').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form'>
  User id:
  <input type='text' id='id' />
  <button onclick='load()'>GO</button>
</div>
<pre id="rep"></pre>
```

Comment: FYI, if you don't use a token you'll have a tiny quota depending on how active your site is.

Comment: Yeah, 300 requests per day I think.

Comment: Caching on your side would help that.

Comment: @Script47 Actually, you're most likely talking about an API key. A token is a different thing wrt. the SE API. API keys are obtained by the app/script author on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com). Tokens are obtained for the user and app/script combination through an OAuth2 flow. Without an API key, there are 300 requests/24 hour period/IP address. With an API key, there are 10k requests/24 hour period/IP address (both quotas shared with everything from that IP address). With a token, that app & user has 10k requests/24 hour period. See: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle